# Manually attach package to Laravel (unable to use composer due to firewall)

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, dompdf

I can't use composer to handle my dependencies due to the corporate firewall. At the moment I'm trying to use [Barry vd Heuvel's DomPDF wrapper for Laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) and tried to:

1. Download the zipfile from Github (master)
2. Updated `composer.json` (not sure if its needed, but did it anyway) and added `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "*"` in the `require` container.
3. Create the folder structure: `vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`
4. Place all files from the package in there (`config`-folder, `src`-folder and the files `.gitignore`, `composer.json` and `readme.md`)
5. Add the service provider and facade in my `app.php`. Service provider is listed as `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class` and the facade is aliased like `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class`
6. Ran `composer dump-autoload`

After refreshing the browser I'm getting `Class 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider' not found`. I also tried to run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan dump-autoload` but the last one fails over the fact it can't find `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider`.

What have I forgotten to do to make it work?

**Update**
I've tried the suggested answer from Wouter J and the composer.json now looks like:

```
..
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\": "vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src"
    },
..
```

I've verified if the composer dump-autoload had any effect but I think it had. Because the entry is now also listed in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` like:

```
return array(
 // more entries
 'Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\' => array($vendorDir . '/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src'),
 'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/app'),
);
```

I believe at this point this is working, but the Facade isn't responding. When I try to call something like `PDF::loadView(...)` and I let PhpStorm import the class (`vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/PDF.php`) it throws an error I can't call the method loadView statically. According to the documentation I should be able to call it like this:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

But that results in `Non-static method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::loadView() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context` on my end.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Composer autoload still doesn't know anything about how to download the package. You have to configure autoloading like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Namespace\\Of\\The\\Package\\": "vendor/the/package" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I don't think he need to include the package name in the composer.json.

Comment: @JilsonThomas I did include it there for situations where the app gets put out of this environment and all dependencies are listed correct. I agree it doesn't have any use at this moment.

Comment: And also make `composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but since I don't see any solution, here is mine: I had exactly the same problem. Was able to solve by running `composer dumpautoload` on my localhost and then copied the folder 'vendor/composer' to the shared hosting without an SSH access. Hope this will help someone in similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem addresses that application don't know about `DomPDF\ServiceProvidor` or anything related to `DomPDF` because `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` itself depends `dpmpdf/dompdf` package which is still missing and does not comes with `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

the package `dompdf/dompdf` also depends on several extension i.e.

```
PHP version 5.3.0 or higher
DOM extension
GD extension
MBString extension
php-font-lib
php-svg-lib
```

have a look at package here https://packagist.org/packages/dompdf/dompdf download this and put in your vendor directory then update your `composer dumpautoload` it should be working